# What are the differences between broadcaster and publisher

Tags: ros, publisher, broadcaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am new to ROS, and I just learned some ROS tutorials. I found that in some tutorials, they refer to a node as the "publisher", such as the "image publisher" in http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages. However, in other tutorials, they refer to a node as the "broadcaster", such as the "tf broadcaster" in http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29. Furthermore, the recipients of them, subscribers and listeners, are not the same either.

I noticed that they all send messages to topics, but subscribers have callback functions that listeners do not have. But

1. I do not know the reasons for creating these two different nodes, or classes.
2. Can I use the function subscribe() to subscribe to a topic from the broadcaster? Can they communicate with each other?

Thanks for any help or hints in advance. Sorry if I missed any information that already existed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400627/what-are-the-differences-between-broadcaster-and-publisher/) by [Arete](https://answers.ros.org/users/104891/arete/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: subscriber and publisher are ROS-wide classes, listener and broadcaster are TF-specific classes.

Long answer: ROS uses a subscriber/publisher model to transfer data between nodes. A node can listen to or publish to a specific topic, which communicates a specific data type. For example, `nodeA` and `nodeB` want to communicate with each other about the ROS msg `std_msgs::Float64` which is communicated through the topic `/topic1`. `nodeA` has a publisher class that creates the data and publishes it on `topic1`, while at the same time, `nodeB` has a callback function that is subscribing to `topic1` and then extracts the data from the `std_msgs::Float64` and utilizes it in whatever way is needed.

TF is a specific library within ROS that is used to perform transformation operations in a helpful manner. With TF you can create a frame tree, add children to an existing parent frame, add a new branch, get the relationship between frames, etc. TF has implemented it's own classes called listener and broadcaster so as not to confuse between subscriber and publisher. Under the hood, listener and broadcaster utilize the ROS subscriber and publisher model, but do not expose them to the user, instead giving other tools to be able to do what the user wants, but specifically is working within the transformation tree, which is usually exposed on the `/tf` and `/tf_static` topics.

Theoretically, you could subscribe to the `/tf` or `/tf_static` topics and do your own math, but it is largely taken care of by the TF library.

Anyway, long answer to say that the TF library is specifically designed for working with transformation math, whereas subscriber/publisher are the overall ROS way of moving data around between any two nodes, not just TF nodes.

---

Originally posted by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) with karma: 261 on 2022-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arete](https://answers.ros.org/users/104891/arete/) on 2022-05-16**:
Thank you so much for your exhaustive explanation.